# What is the mechanism behind a `for` loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust, foreach, iterator

The rust language reference seems to describe the desugaring of for loops in terms of calling `IntoIterator::into_iter` on the expression provided after the `in` keyword in order to obtain an `Iterator`, then use that `Iterator` to retrieve the elements to loop over.

However, in practice the for loop seems to work just fine with expressions of either `IntoIterator` or `Iterator`:

```rs
let v = vec!(1, 2, 3);

// Either of these work:
for i in v { ... }               // v             impl IntoIterator
for i in v.into_iter() { ... }   // v.into_iter() impl Iterator
```

So the acutal rule seems to be: If the expression is already an `Iterator`, loop over that, otherwise, call `into_iter` on the expression to the get an `Iterator` to loop over. However, thats not what the documentation is saying.

So what am I missing? Is the documentation incomplete? Is there some magic going on with the `IntoIterator::into_iter` call? Or do `Iterator`s also implement `IntoIterator` to make it work? Or did I completely misunderstand how it works?

Comment: `IntoIterator` is automatically implemented for anything that implements `Iterator`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-25

Comment: @isaactfa: Thanks, I overlooked that in the vast number of impls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a blanket implementation of `IntoIterator` for types implementing `Iterator`, that returns the iterator itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.63.0/src/core/iter/traits/collect.rs.html#266-274). Thus, if you take `IntoIterator` you can work with `Iterator`s too.